# How do I solve a general formula for a very complicated list of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

So I have been given a table of numbers and I have figured out the pattern but have no idea what the general formula for the sequence is. Here is the sequence:

| n | m |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 128 |
| 5 | 650 |
| 6 | 3912 |

I realised that the m-value is equal to the n-value multiplied by the previous m-value and then 2*n-value is added to create the m-value, but I'm not sure how to put this into a formula. Please help it would be much appreciated, and explanations as to how to do these in the future are much appreciated.

Comment: This kind of problems shouldn't be as widespread as they are. Any finite sequence of numbers allows an infinite number of solutions.  It's just guesswork usually

Comment: i just need to know how to write it down cause its confusing. its solved but how to write out the equation is eluding me. and its not finite, thats just what they gave me, the sequence is infinite

Comment: There is no guarantee that the pattern you spotted was the correct pattern that would successfully describe the rest of the list.  There are infinitely many different patterns that all describe the same start but continue in different ways.  As for describing the pattern you have spotted... this is a standard first-order non-linear [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) $f(n) = 2n + n\cdot f(n-1)$ with initial condition $f(2)=8$.  It doesn't have the prettiest closed form solution (*as is common for nonlinear*), involving the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: oh my word the text bugged out so it was a jumble when i saw this the first. Coming back to it i see how it works thanks

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Although there can be infinitely many solutions, the way you can write your relation is in the form of a recurrence relation. You can think of the $m$ value that corresponds to $n$ as $f(n)$, and the previous $m$ value as $f(n-1)$.

With these, try to define $f(n)$ in terms of $f(n-1)$ and $n$ according to your pattern.

Comment: Yes thank you. I was trying to figure out a way to write it so I could use a Java program to give me all solutions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence sequence defined by $f(n) = n f(n-1)+2n$ with $f(2)=8$ can be explicitly calculated as $$f(n) = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{k!}$$

Comment: $f_n=c \,\Gamma (n+1)+2 e n \,\Gamma (n,1)$ is just a bit more explicit

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I asked a very smart friend and he came up with this more simplified version than JMoravitz in the comments. Its the exact same but easier on the eyes ;)

$f(n)$ $=n(f(n-1))+2n$

Thanks everybody for all the help!